# Flask SQLAlchemy join tables

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have these tables

```py
class Employee(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    employeeproject = db.relationship("Employeeproject")

    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
    ):
        self.name = name
```

```py
class Employeeproject(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    employee_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("employee.id"))
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    project = db.relationship("Project")

    def __init__(self, employee_id: str, project_id: int):
        self.employee_id = employee_id
        self.project_id = project_id
```

```py
class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)

    description = db.Column(db.String(300), unique=True)

    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        description: str,
    ):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
```

I want to link these tables. Any suggestions on how to do that?

I tried joining like but it didn't work:

```py
result = Employee.query.join(
            Employeeproject, Employee.id == Employeeproject.employee_id
        ).all()[0]
```

I already read the docs, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the `Employeeproject` model, you try to setup a `db.relationship` with the `Project` model, the thing is you haven't set up a `db.ForeignKey` in the `project_id`, also you can establish relationships in both `Employee` and `Project` models to `Employeeproject`.

```
class Employee(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    projects = db.relationship('Employeeproject', backref='employee')

class Employeeproject(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'employeeproject'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    employee_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('employee.id'))
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.id'))
    project = db.relationship('Project', backref='employeeproject')

class Project(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'project'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(300))
    employees = db.relationship('Employeeproject', backref='project')
```

This is how you can join the tables:

```
result = db.session.query(Employee).join(
    Employeeproject, Employee.id == Employeeproject.employee_id
).join(
    Project, Employeeproject.project_id == Project.id
).all()
```

If you want to access the projects of an employee, you can do so by using the projects attribute

```
employee = result[0]  
for project_relation in employee.projects:
    print(project_relation.project.name)
```